# Mini-HDMI to VGA for presentations on laptop without VGA out?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, vga

Are there any mini-HDMI to VGA cables that actually work for presentations on a projector (no copy-protected movie viewing required)? All of the ones reviewed on Amazon have one star and are marked as scams, with notes that a digital-to-analog converter box is required.

I'm looking at the [Samsung 9 Series laptop](http://www.engadget.com/2011/03/28/samsung-series-9-900x-laptop-review/), which has no direct VGA out, does not come with a conversion cable, and Samsung does not sell a conversion cable of their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this may be the VGA dongle needed for the Samsung Series 9:

http://www.provantage.com/samsung-aa-ah0namb~7SAMV05M.htm

It's now being sold on several sites EXCEPT for Samsung's site. The part number is consistent across sites, however.

Comment: That is indeed the dongle you need. I just purchased a Series 9 and also picked up the dongle. Keep in mind, this is a proprietary dongle and as far as I know, the only one that will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a VGA dongle that works with the Series 7. It is on the Samsung website at http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops-accessories/AA-AV1N12B/US as well as the Provantage site at http://www.provantage.com/samsung-aa-av1n12b~7SAMV05T.htm. The Series 7 and 9 require different dongles, so be careful!

If you go to Samsung.com, they have a "compatability checker" at the bottom of the product description page, so after you search for the product you are interested in purchasing, go to Samsung.com and look it up.(I also found it a few dollars cheaper on Samsung.com).